# How to run a job in midnight using pentaho data integration (spoon)?

Tags: etl, pentaho

i'm setting up a job that run in midnight while we're not at work so in the next morning our job is done. but unfortunately the job is not working.

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: Are you scheduling the job using spoon utility? How did you scheduled the job?

Comment: yes. i'm using spoon to run the job. I made job scheduling in the step start type : monthy, time of day : 02 day of month : 11

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the included scripts to run jobs from the system scheduler.

- Windows: use kitchen.bat and run it from task scheduler
- Linux: use kitchen.sh from crond

Here is the syntax to use:

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Products/Data_Integration/Command_Line_Tools